# Django - Exclude current post from side bar

Tags: python, django

I am playing with Django but I'm having trouble with my templates. In my post detail in including a recent posts side bar from a template tag but I want to exclude the current post if it is, in fact, one of the most recent. My original hope was to use .exclude(id__post_detail=post) in the blog_tag but I think I might be missing an important concept, do I need to request post_detail return its response and then I can do that? Or perhaps define the query in the view and then call it to the blog_tag?

Many thanks in advance.

1.blog_tags.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from ..models import Post

@register.inclusion_tag('blog/sidebar.html')
def sidebar_latest(request, count=5):     
    latest_posts= Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')[:count]
    return {'latest_posts': latest_posts}
```

2. views

   ```
   def post_detail(request, pk):
       post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
       return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
   ```
3. post_detail

   ```
   {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
   {% load blog_tags %}
   {% block content %}
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
   <div class="post">
   <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
   {% if post.published_date %}
   <div class="date">
   {{ post.published_date }}
   </div>
   {% endif %}
   <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
   {% sidebar_latest 3 %}
   </div>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

Comment: def sidebar_latest(request, count=5,**kwargs): and try to print the kwargs inside the function, and check if the post id of the current post is displayed or not when you go to the details page

Comment: Hm that has taken me on an interesting route of reading but unfortunately not answered my question.

Comment: i havent said it will be the answer, i just asked if you get the id of the current post or not? if you get it then the filtering can be done

Comment: did you put the kwargs in the template filter function?? then on the first line of the function print(kwargs) and go to a post detail page, and check what is printed in the terminal for the kwargs, and post that output her\e

Comment: first make the function like this ef sidebar_latest(request, count=5, **kwargs)

Comment: [28/Jul/2017 16:16:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7102
{}
[28/Jul/2017 16:16:15] "GET /post/5/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3774

Comment: @register.inclusion_tag('blog/sidebar.html')
def sidebar_latest(request, count=5,**kwargs):
 print(kwargs)
 latest_posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')[:count]
 return {'latest_posts': latest_posts}

Comment: It shows nothing, no matter where I put it. Are you able to explain what you were hoping to see and how it would help me?